# Netbeans GUI: no content in frame

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm new to Java and I'm searching on this problem for too long now. I hope you guys can help me.

I'm writing this app called Lingo. I created a frame with some labels, a textfield and six panels. When I run the project, I just get a white frame, without content. None of the components (except the textfield) are shown.

When I debug and the debugger passed the `.setVisible(true)` method, I get the same white frame without content but no textfield either! The debugger gives this error that I can't understand.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?
Thanks!

[image]

[Full-size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlfce.jpg)

Comment: Show us the (complete) Java code instead of an image of your IDE.

Comment: Please include the code instead.

Comment: want the code to check @two